# MonoDevelop not running after upgrading mono from 3.2 to 3.8

Tags: mono, monodevelop, roslyn

I get this error while trying to run monodevelop in ubuntu 14.10

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Earlier monodevelop was running normally. I want to use it for running RoslynLight.sln but there I got the error:

Project does not support framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'

I read an answer somewhere that I must be using an older version of mono so I upgraded it which lead me to the above error.

Could anyone suggest a solution for this? I am new to both mono and roslyn, so it is possible that I am doing something very wrong somewhere

Comment: Mono and MonoDevelop should be updated the same time. Only updating one of them is not enough. You probably should now upgrade Mono and MonoDevelop to the latest, by following http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

Comment: @LexLi tried it. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you update to Mono 4.0.x instead?